# How to solve Paypal 10548 Error

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-payments-pro

I am facing error #10548, how can I solve this error?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Issue**
PayPal returned API error code 10548 - Invalid Configuration. This transaction cannot be processed.

**Causes**
This error usually occurs if you don't have a business account. You must have a business PayPal account within a PayPal Payments Pro-enabled country to use the Direct Payment API. The absence of a home or customer service phone number on your PayPal account can also trigger this error.

**Solution**
If you have a business account and you get this error, check your PayPal account profile and make sure it includes a home phone number or a customer service phone number. Update your profile if necessary.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @ Mageto2 Learner :   Actually paypal won't give API details if not any requied details not filled. But i got API details. and business https://snag.gy/v3UwDP.jpg .  Still what i need to fill?

Comment: @ Mageto2 Learner :  still what i need to fill?

Comment: There is some problem about your account 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errors/
go here and check for 10548 error it is also saying same thing.

Comment: @ Mageto2 Learner : yes, how can i solve these kind of error

Comment: @ Mageto2 Learner : is it necessary go to create paypal payment pro account ? i have already paypal account?

Comment: I am not more clear on that if Paypal pro require or not for me just paypal business is working fine.